# how to remove a previous commit locally

Tags: git, github

Right now, this is at local setting, ie my computer.

I did some changes and was satisfied with it, hence me doing `git commit -m "message here"`

Then I realize that one of the files has info that I don't want in github repository.

So I went and changed that file's info.

But when I run `git status`, I can still see my previous commit - obviously.

Haven't run a new commit yet.

How do I make sure that when I run a new commit that particular info in that commit won't go up to Github?

Advice?

EDIT

Basically I don't want to remove my previous commit because that means undoing some of the other work. I just want to remove original text that commit holds, and which since then I've changed.

In other words, how do I add the since then modified file to the previous commit so it'll overwrite it and can be included in that commit before it's pushed up?

Let me know if this needs further clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the latest commit by doing git commit --ammend. If you've added some changes (git add ) these changes will go into that commit possibly overwriting some data there (i.e. if you added a line and then removed a line there will be no line at all). You will also have an opportunity to edit the commit message.

It is also possible to alter history arbitrary with git rebase -i (including but not limited to altering any past commits, reordering them or merging a number of commits together).

Comment: Zavarisky, just discovered that right now before I saw your answer. =)  But thank you!

Comment: It's worth mentioning, I think, that "amend" is a sort of "white lie": git doesn't (and *can't*) change the other commit, it just makes a *new* one and shoves the old one aside, as it were, and then hides the old one from you so that you don't *see* it.  (And it won't get pushed either.)

Comment: @torek, thanks for letting me know. Interesting! As long it doesn't get pushed to GitHub, for me it's a non-issue, but it's good to know that it's still in the history.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543: yes, it's in your reflogs (`git reflog` or `git reflog branchname`) in case you need it back for some reason.  The reflog entries expire (by default, in 30 days for "junk" commits, 90 for still-reachable commits) and only after that point does the commit really get removed.  But since only the reflog "sees" it, push won't push it, unless you specify it by a reflog-name or its raw commit-ID.